# Calling object methods within Arrays.reduce(...)

Tags: java, oop, object, java-8

I have the following 3 files,

A.java:

```
class A {

    private float b;    

    public A(float b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public float getB() {
        return b;
    }

}
```

C.java:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class C {

    private A[] d;
    private int i = 0;

    public C() {
        d = new A[2];
    }

    public float totalB() {
        return Arrays.stream(d).reduce((e, f) -> e.getB() + f.getB()).get();
    }

    public void addB(A b) {
        d[i++] = b;
    }

}
```

D.java:

```
class D {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C c = new C();
        c.addB(new A(3));
        c.addB(new A(5));
        System.out.println(c.totalB())
    }

}
```

I was expecting the last line in D.java to output 8, however I get this error:

`error: incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression
        return Arrays.stream(d).reduce((e, f) -> e.getB() + f.getB()).get();
                                                          ^
    float cannot be converted to A`

Why does this happen? I don't see where I'm converting the floats to the object A.

Comment: Is it intended that your totalB() method returns an int instead of a float?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The single argument `reduce()` variant expects the final result of the reduce operation to be of the same type as the `Stream` elements.

You need a [different variant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-):

```
<U> U reduce(U identity,
             BiFunction<U, ? super T, U> accumulator,
             BinaryOperator<U> combiner);
```

which you can use as follows:

```
public float totalB() {
    return Arrays.stream(d).reduce(0.0f,(r, f) -> r + f.getB(), Float::sum);
}
```

Comment: or Arrays.stream(d).reduce(0,(r, f) -> r + (int)f.getB(), Integer::sum);

Comment: Thanks, this works. Could you also please link the appropriate documentation for this?

Comment: @Eran Also, I believe it should be possible to do this operation without using the combiner variant which is used only for parallel streams.

Comment: @AnkurChrungoo I thought so too, but the reduce variant without the combiner results in the same type as the Stream element (`T reduce(T identity, BinaryOperator<T> accumulator)`), so it doesn't fit here.

Comment: @Eran, yes, but I mean't another way, i.e. probably using map() to map it to int/float based stream, and then using reduce() on it.

Comment: @Eran I posted the alternative in an answer below.

Answer (score 13):

I prefer utilizing the "sum" method as it's more readable than the general `reduce` pattern. i.e.

```
return (float)Arrays.stream(d)
                    .mapToDouble(A::getB)
                    .sum();
```

This is the more idiomatic, readable and efficient approach as opposed to your approach of `Arrays.stream(d).reduce(...)`...

Comment: Yeah I was thinking to use it but had to use maptodouble which I didn’t quite like :)

Comment: And I hope there was a method mapToFloat, making this more intuitive and probably more efficient.

Comment: @AnkurChrungoo where’s the problem with `mapToDouble`? Doing the arithmetic in `double` instead of `Float` will be much faster. And no, calculating in `float` is unlikely to be more efficient, as all real life FPUs calculate in `double` (or with even higher precision) and forcing a lower precision (truncating the result after each step) may cost even more time.

Comment: @Holger oh is it? Is this more efficient space and time complexity wise? Would appreciate if you could share some detailed insight. Thanks!

Comment: @Holger and if we think about space complexity, which one is better?

Comment: @AnkurChrungoo keep in mind that streams are not about storage, but only calculations. Once the JIT/HotSpot optimizer did its work, all intermediate values reside in CPU registers anyway, and the CPU registers always have the same width. The only drawback is that there is no way to create a `float[]` array from a stream as a result. But here, we get only one final value which we can just cast anyway. One of the API developers once said in a comment on SO that they even considered omitting the `IntStream` in favor of `LongStream` but felt that “the developers are not ready for that (yet)”…

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in my comment above, posting another alternative where you don't need the second version of the reduce method.

```
public float totalB() {
    return Arrays.stream(d).map(i -> i.getB()).reduce(Float::sum).get();
}
```

Comment: or better --> `return Arrays.stream(d).map(A::getB).reduce(Float::sum).orElse(0f);`

Comment: @Aomine or `… .reduce(0f, Float::sum)`